# cvLoadImage not working in Xcode using C

Tags: c++, c, xcode, opencv

I recently met a problem when I try to use cvLoadImage and cvShowImage in Xcode using C Language. However, here comes an error as:"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=1, address=0*2603d20)". Then, I try to implement the same function in Xcode using C++, and the error disappears, can anyone tell me what's going on here? Thanks a lot!

```
 int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    IplImage* img;
    img_file_name="/Users/zhihaozhu/Documents/OpenCV Test/Panorama/img.png";
    img = cvLoadImage( img_file_name, 1 );
    cvShowImage("dfsaj", img);  //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=1,address=0*2603d20)
    IplImage* gray32 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
img_file_name="/Users/zhihaozhu/Documents/OpenCV Test/Panorama/img.png";
//                                              ^
```

There shouldn't be a space in the image's path. Try escape:

```
img_file_name="/Users/zhihaozhu/Documents/OpenCV\\ Test/Panorama/img.png";
```

or (preferably) move the image to a directory without a space in its path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried that, and it didn't work, I think it's not the problem of image path, but thanks anyway